# How to load the external images in a div using proxy in html2canvas in php

Tags: php, jquery, proxy, html2canvas

I am trying to capture a part of div using html2canvas library. everything going well but html2canvas doesn't capture the external(other domain) images. For this, I am using the proxy to load the cross-domain images in a frame. I getting the following error in console.

[image]

Script file:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#capture").click(function(){

    html2canvas($('#preview-container').get(0),{logging:true,useCORS: true,proxy:'<?=base_url()?>proxy'},{}).then( function (canvas) {
    console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
   dataURL= canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.9).split(',')[1];

        $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Client-ID **********'
        },
        data: {
            image: dataURL
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        error:function(response){

        console.log(response);

        },
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.success) {
                alert(response.data.link);
               // window.location = response.data.link;

            }
        }
    });


 });



});
});
</script>
```

**Proxy Code**

https://codeshare.io/G6MOzQ